# Should we remove Child added by addChild method before going to next scene in cocos2d?

Tags: cocoa-touch, cocos2d-iphone, addchild

I am writing a small game in cocos2d. I am adding child

```
    [ self addChild: sprite1];
```

Should I remove these before going to next scene by using

```
 [self removeChild: sprite1 cleanup:YES];
```

Does it increase  the performance in device ?

Thank You.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer, no. The scene will do its own cleanup and release its child nodes when it deallocates. So as long as you send `[super dealloc];` in your scene's `- (void)dealloc` you'll be fine.